# SublimeCodeIntel and Symfony2 autoloading

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am trying to move from PHPStorm to Sublime Text 3 but I got stuck on the autocomplete using SublimeCodeIntel in conjunction with Symfony 2. How can I make SublimeCodeIntel to scan all the `vendor/` and `src/` directory of my project?

Right now whenever I'm in the controller and I'm typing something like

```
$response = new Response()
$response->get
```

I get `Warning: evaluating 'Request' at GamesController.php#27: could not resolve first part of 'Request'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, select the `Settings-Default` and `Settings-User` options under `Preferences -> Packages -> SublimeCodeIntel`. Copy the full text of the `Default` file and paste it into the `User` file, which should be empty if you haven't customized the plugin at all. You can now close the `Default` file.

Now, in the main body of the preferences, set

```json
"codeintel_max_recursive_dir_depth": 25,
"codeintel_scan_files_in_project": true,
```

Next, scroll down to the bottom to the `codeintel_config` array, and edit the PHP section to the following:

```json
    "PHP": {
        "phpExtraPaths": ["/path/to/library/files", "/another/path"],
        "codeintel_scan_files_in_project": true,
        "codeintel_max_recursive_dir_depth": 25
    }
```

Save the file, restart Sublime, and you should be all set. If for some reason it's still not working, go to your `~/.codeintel/db` directory and delete the `PHP` directory. You may also find a similar directory in the root of your project, so if it exists go ahead and delete that one too. This forces a reindexing of your code and includes, and since it's based on your new config options everything should work as expected. Remember that reindexing can take some time, so be patient.

Good luck!

Comment: The same worked with FuelPHP and CakePHP. I did the same at first, but only increased to 10 from 5, and that was not enough. Thanks!